# Run Selenium tests in multiple browsers with a base class

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Let's say I Have code:

```
namespace SeleniumTests 
{
    [TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
    [TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
    public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver : IWebDriver, new()
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void CreateDriver () {
            this.driver = new TWebDriver();
        }

        [Test]
        public void GoogleTest() {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            query.SendKeys("Bread" + Keys.Enter);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            Assert.AreEqual("bread - Google Search", driver.Title);
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I want block

```
    [SetUp]
    public void CreateDriver () {
        this.driver = new TWebDriver();
    }
```

move to base class. But I do not know in this case how inherited from the base class. How do I handle `<TWebDriver> where TWebDriver: IWebDriver, new ()`?

Comment: Good question, but I look at the `[SetUp]` as a Unit Test Constructor almost. What I do is very similar but instead of creating the new Instance in the `[SetUp]` I call off to a static method that takes in a Generic `IWebDriver` and does lots of setup like connects to the Selenium GRID server, sets window size etc.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't use generics like your example but instead kind of works like dependency injection.

You need a method to create the instance of the webdriver.

```
public class DriverFactory
{
    public IWebDriver Driver { get; set; }

    public enum DriverType
    {
        IE,
        Firefox,
        Chrome
    }

    public IWebDriver GetDriver(DriverType typeOfDriver)
    {
        if (typeOfDriver == DriverType.IE) return new InternetExplorerDriver();
        if (typeOfDriver == DriverType.Chrome) return new ChromeDriver();
        return new FirefoxDriver(); // return firefox by default
    }
}
```

Then call from your setup:

```
[Setup]
public void CreateDriver()
{
    var driverFactory = new DriverFactory();
    this.driver = driverFactory.GetDriver(DriverType.Chrome);
}
```

You can inherit the class:

```
public class TestWithMultipleBrowsers : DriverFactory
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is this solution allows you to run a single test immediately turn on multiple browsers? Indeed, this is precisely what allows you to do [TestFixture (typeof (ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture (typeof (InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture (typeof (FirefoxDriver))]
But I do not understand how to initialize push in the base class.