# Scope of Variables in SetUpFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have several files that will require access to an object, which I want initialized only once. I considered making a static variable, but I'd rather stay away from that. Here's my question along with code:

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class TestSetup
{
    public IWebDriver driver;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Dispose();
    }
}
```

*Do my tests within the namespace of this SetUpFixture have access to driver?*

EDIT: Looks like an approach to this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079070/run-selenium-tests-in-multiple-browsers-with-a-base-class/29079415#29079415). I'm still open to other options than what Jon pointed out.

Comment: You could have a static class that creates the driver object or make a driver factory class that is not static but creates instances of the driver.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079070/run-selenium-tests-in-multiple-browsers-with-a-base-class/29079415#29079415